# Identify if a column in a matrix is the product of other columns of the same matrix

Tags: matrices

I read that linear transformation can be used to identify the linear combination between the columns(or rows) of a matrix.

Is there any way to identify the product between the columns?

Eg : Given this matrix, is there any way to identify that C3 = C2 * C1

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 5 & 5 \\
    2 & 7 & 14 \\
    3 & 11 & 33 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Take the log of all elements...

Comment: Log does not work if the relation is C3 = 2C2 *C1. Should i take 2 as a common multiple before reducing the matrix to row echelon form?